# How can i write the html code on Zend Framework

Tags: css, html, zend-framework, php

I have this code `

**THE**

```
        <div class="input-prepend">
           <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
           <input type="text" placeholder="Username">
        </div>

        <div class="input-prepend">

          <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-lock"></i></span>
          <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
          <a href="index.html"><span class="add-on" id="login"><i class="icon-arrow-right"></i></span></a>

        </div>
```

and I want to write on file .phtml on zend framework I work with MVC 
can you please help me how can I write that on file .phtml on zend framework 
so i use this `<?php echo $this->element->loginAd->renderViewHelper(); ?>` and i don't know how i do that `<span class="add-on">
                <i class="icon-user"></i>
                </span>`in Syntxe same of the zend view 
i want do the same of the theme html/css 
and when i write this code

```
 `<form class="form-signin" name="login-form" id="login-form" method="<?php echo $this->escape($this->element->getMethod()); ?>" action="<?php echo $this->escape($this->element->getAction()); ?>">
            <h2   class="form-signin-headin

g"><strong>Administration</strong></h2>
            <div class="input-prepend">
                <span class="add-on">
                <i class="icon-user"></i>
                </span>

                <?php echo $this->element->loginAd->renderViewHelper(); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="input-prepend">
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-lock"></i></span>
                <?php echo $this->element->password->renderViewHelper(); ?>
                <a href="index.html"><span class="add-on" id="login"><i class="icon-arrow-right"></i></span></a>
            </div>

            <?php echo $this->element->submit->renderViewHelper(); ?>
            <p class="input-height">
                <input type="checkbox" name="keep-logged" id="keep-logged" value="1" class="mini-switch" checked="checked">
                <label for="keep-logged" class="inline"><?=$this->translate('Stay connected');?></label>
            </p>
        </form>`
```

Thanks for your great help

Answer (score 0):

> You need to follow the following steps 
>   1. Create a form

```
namespace Application\Form;

use Zend\Form\Form;
use Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;
class UserForm extends Form
{
    public function __construct()

    {
        parent::__construct('usser');
        $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');

        $this->addElement(
            'text', 'username', array(
                'label' => 'Username:',
                'required' => true,
                'filters'    => array('StringTrim'),
            ));

        $this->addElement('password', 'password', array(
            'label' => 'Password:',
            'required' => true,
            ));

        $this->addElement('submit', 'submit', array(
            'ignore'   => true,
            'label'    => 'Login',
            ));

    }
}
```

> 2 instantiate that form in controller or factory what ever is best for
>   you

```
public function indexAction(){
    $form = new UserForm($dbAdapter);
        return array('form'=>$form);

}
```

> 1. in your view script index.phtml

```
<?php
$title = 'New Admin User ';
$this->headTitle($title);
?>
<h1><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($title); ?></h1>
<?php
$form = $this->form;
$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('user', array('action' => 'index')));
$form->prepare();

echo $this->form()->openTag($form);

foreach ($form as $element) { ?>

 <?php
echo $this->formRow($element); ?>



<?php }?>
<?php
echo $this->form()->closeTag();
```

Comment: Thank you for yours answer but i have the code i want do same of that `<?php echo $this->element->loginAd->renderViewHelper(); ?>` how can i write that `<span class="add-on">
    <i class="icon-user"></i>
    </span>`

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the exact same html code, just replacing the input with

```
<?php echo $this->formElement($form->get('name')) ?>
```

A complete example would be:

```
<?php echo $this->form()->openTag($form) ?>
<div class="form-group">
    <?php echo $this->formLabel($form->get('name')); ?>
    <?php echo $this->formElement($form->get('name')); ?>
</div>
<?php echo $this->form()->closeTag($form) ?>
```

For the placeholder, see amarjit sngh solution.